# How can I display a result after I have done some calculations in one of the forms data using just Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Let me make myself clear, Please check out this screenshot: https://prnt.sc/kv4fsm

I have this table: **calculation** in database whereas I got these columns: id, value_1, value_2, operator and result.

So far what I have done is that I can successfully insert data in the table and perform the calculation. However, what problem I am facing is that I just want to show the result right beneath **Calculate** button as in the screenshot. My question is that is there any way to hide the **"Result"** field so that It will only show when the Submit button is clicked?

I have used the **Laravel Collective** for creating form and insertion. I am not so sure what I am supposed to do with the Result part after also checking the documentation of Laravel Collective as they don't mention about any field which has been retrieved after doing some action.

Here's a bit of code **calculate.blade.php**- a view file.

```
   @extends('layouts.app')


@section('content')

<div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Calculate</div>
                {!! Form::open(['action'=> 'CalculatorController@store', 'method'=> 'POST']) !!}

                {{Form::bsInt('value_1', '',['placeholder' => 'First Value'])}}
                {{Form::bsInt('value_2', '',['placeholder' => 'Second Value'])}}
                {{Form::bsOp('operator', '',['placeholder' => 'Operator'])}}
                {{Form::bsSubmit('Calculate', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) }}

                {{Form::bsResult('result', '' ,['placeholder' => 'Result'])}}

                {!! Form:: close() !!}

                <div class="card-body">



            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

So, can you guys please give me any suggestion on this? Thanks.

Please note: I am a beginner in Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

if you need it in the same page you will need learn javascript for that.
but you can calculate the result in controller and send it to another page.!

Comment: I can redirect the result in another page as I have already done that . I just wanted to use only Laravel to sort this out. I know JavaScript would be a better approach but I just want to learn whether it is possible to do so what I am asking with Laravel or not. Thanks